# Change the bookmarking state directory when saving to disk

Tags: r, shiny

When saving bookmarks to disk, by default the state directory where bookmarks are saved will be created within the app directory as *shiny_bookmarks*. Is there any way to overwrite the default state directory?

I tried to do this by assigning the desired path to `state$dir` within `onBookmark` but this does not seem to work (see MRE below).

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- function(request) {

  fluidPage(
    textInput("txt", "Enter text"),
    checkboxInput("caps", "Capitalize"),
    verbatimTextOutput("out"),
    bookmarkButton()
  )

}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out <- renderText({
    if (input$caps)
      toupper(input$txt)
    else
      input$txt
  })

  # Define default path (to be changed later)
  switch(Sys.info()[['sysname']],
         Windows = {path <<- gsub("\\\\", "/", file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"),"Desktop",fsep="/"))},
         Mac = {path <<- "~/Desktop"})

  onBookmark(function(state) {

    # Change working directory to target directory for bookmarks:
    id = gsub(sprintf("%s/shiny_bookmarks/",getwd()), "", state$dir) # get unique id
    state$dir = sprintf("%s/shiny_bookmarks/%s", path, id)

  })

}

enableBookmarking(store="server")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would have expected the bookmarks to be saved in the specified `state$dir`, but they are still saved in app directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since got [help](https://community.rstudio.com/t/changing-bookmark-state-directory-when-saving-to-disk/37877/2) on this and found a fix that seems to be working. The key is to use custom callback functions (as below) which Shiny uses under the bonnet to save and restore the bookmarked state. The `myBookmarks$path` is the desired local directory outside of the app directory and specified by the user through `shinyFiles::shinyDirChoose`. For more detail see also this [github thread](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2537).

```
my_save_interface <- function(id, callback) {
      stateDir <- file.path(myBookmarks$path, "shiny_bookmarks", id)
      if (!shiny:::dirExists(stateDir)) {
        dir.create(stateDir, recursive = TRUE)
      }

      callback(stateDir)
    }

my_load_interface <- function(id, callback) {
      myBookmarksPath <- getShinyOption("myBookmarksPath")
      print(myBookmarksPath)
      stateDir <- file.path(myBookmarksPath, "shiny_bookmarks", id)
      callback(stateDir)
    }

shinyOptions(save.interface = my_save_interface, load.interface = my_load_interface)
```